# How can I change my windows 8 publisher display name?

Tags: windows-8

I have a registered Windows 8 Developer account. I do not have any applications published or event sent for testing. Is it possible for me to change the publisher name I requested originally?

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is really on-topic here. If not, I'm thinking if [programmers.se] is the place to go.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I disagree

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible.  From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh967786.aspx):

> The publisher display name is the name under which your apps are
>   listed in the Windows Store.
>
> Note  You can change this after you sign up, but, if you decide to do
>   this, you will need to modify that entry in your app's packages,
>   upload the updated packages, and then submit the apps for
>   certification again.

On this page, it also tells you how to change this info.  To access your developer account info, sign into your developer account, go to your Windows Store Dashboard, and then click "Account" under Profile in the left menu.

Comment: I have an issue with this that I hope you might be able to clarify. My client created an account with an erroneous publisher display name. Unaware about this setting I publisher version 1.0.0.0 of the app. Then they discovered the error and updated the publisher display name. One week! down the road, the publisher display name was finally verified. I updated the package details in Visual Studio (actually it did this automatically by associating the app with the store), create a new package and uploaded the app again. It was just approved but the publisher display name remains unchanged. Ideas?

Comment: No, I think our client had contact with people at MS and they were eventually able to change it. I don't recall the details though, sorry.